# Export MovieClip to SWF in Flash Player 11?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, export, flash

Can i export a movieclip to SWF with Flash via AS3?

I've tried do this:

```
var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
buffer.writeObject(MOVIE_CLIP_HERE);
buffer.position = 0;
buffer.writeBytes(...);
```

But it doesn't works in Flash Player 11.4.

Comment: I don't get the question. Most likely not just me. What do you want your code to do? There is another "Export to Actionscript" operation which is a pre-compile action in Adobe Flash CSx, and means "create a class with given name".

Comment: I have a MovieClip on the stage. I want export this movieclip to swf, using a command like "filereference.save(mc, 'file.swf')". Can i do this?

Comment: The result won't be an SWF, even if you could save such a movie clip. Saving movie clips, even if it's just a `Shape`, is no easy task. You need to write an implementation of `IExternalizable` interface for your custom class which instance is that MC, or a similar way to turn the movie clip into metadata and backwards.

Comment: Thanks man! Do you have a documentation to do this for me?

Comment: I'd say this is pretty complicated, and it's usually tailored to your personal needs. Say I wanted to export a tower in a tower defence game - I export an int for type, two ints for position and one int for kills (that alter tower's damage), nothing more. When I am about to load that tower, I create a new instance of that tower, set its position, set its kills and say "now, recalculate yourself!" as it'll do each time it kills a monster. So you have to devise a method of what to store about your MC, then probably stuff that data into an `Object`, call `JSON.stringify()` over that and save.